# Can I used addall conditionally?

Tags: list

Can I add a where condition to addAll?
Example:

```
mylist.addAll(OtherList where field__c != o);
```

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, if you have a filtering utility class, you could practically abstract this into a function call: `mylist.addAll(Data.filter(otherlist, Filter.notEqualTo(Obj__c.Field__c, o)));` but that would require finding or writing such a library method (and mine isn't yet available, unfortunately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Apex doesn't have that kind of function application. Just use iterator syntax:

```
for (sObject o : (List<sObject>)otherList) {
    if (o.get('field__c') != SOME_VALUE) {
        myList.add(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't directly do this. You need to first check in if condition then add it the list

```
if(OtherList where field__c != o) {
   mylist.addAll(OtherList);
}
```

But I think you want to check for field in all record then in that case you need

```
for(sObject ob : otherList) { 
    if (ob.get('field__c') != 'o') {
        myList.add(o);
    }
}
```